# How do I store a variable in a function so I can access it from a different file

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

I am trying to make a program that allows you to select a day, and then store a value for the day with a separate file. However, I can't find a way to store the selected day in a variable that I can use.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import *

main = Tk()
main.title('Calendar')
main.geometry('600x400')

cal = Calendar(main, selectmode='day')
cal.pack()


def set_date():
    my_label.config(text=cal.get_date())
    today = cal.get_date()
    print(today)


my_button = Button(main, text='Get Date',command=set_date)
my_button.pack(pady=20)

my_label = Label(main,text="Haha")
my_label.pack(pady=20)

main.mainloop()
```

If I store the vairable inside the function `set_date()` it stores the date that is selected but I can't import it on a separate file. And if I store the variable outside of the function `set_date()` it only stores the current date and not the one selected.

Comment: Functions aren't intended to hold state. You can `return` a value and/or pass something in as an argument. But if you want something that maintains state you should use a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell exactly what you want because of how you worded it, but I'm pretty sure this is what you want

```
def set_date():
    my_label.config(text=cal.get_date())
    today = cal.get_date()
    return today
```

If you then import this function in another file and call it like this

```
selected_date = set_date()
```

This isn't quite what you want though as it will modify the label each time you want to get the date, so you will want to add this function to get the selected date that you want.

```
def get_date():
    today = cal.get_date()
    return today
```